# To create textboxes in cshtml for List<string> in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

am really new to MVC, i was web form developer but i happened to get involved in a project developed using MVC.

My view looks like this, 5 textboxes to enter values (stored as a List), when added will be displayed in a grid on the same view, gird has a edit and delete button. when user clicks on edit button the list of values will appear in each textboxes for the user to edit the values.

My Model has List Values.

Please shed some insight on how to achieve this scenario.

Thank you,

Comment: show us what you have tried. Also is your model defined in Razor as: `@model = IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: when you click on the edit button inside grid the values displayed in textboxes right